# How to get postman tests to Fail - mine are always passing?

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I'm writing a simple Postman test that even checks if `true == false` but it always passes. What am I doing wrong? You can see the green light here:

[image]

Just a single test on its own without the wrapper function will fail [good!], but that doesn't seem a scalable way to write a lot of tests.

so wrapping stuff in `pm.test( )` with either a `function()` or an `()=>`  arrow function means everything false passes... ???

[image]

[image]

If I use a test runner, or check test results below I can see the fails. So maybe that little happy green light in the test authoring panel is just buggy / should be ignored? Or maybe it means syntax error rather than results error? Confusing.

[image]

Comment: if you remove everything from the body of the test except for the true == false test does it still pass?

Comment: updated my question to inc that case.

Comment: I'm not sure that I can see an actual question - What is the problem that you having issues with here? All `pm.expect()` need to be wrapped in a `pm.test` statement to be considered a test. Closing out the `pm.test()` will be considered true and pass the test.

Comment: Why do you think the test is passing? On this screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/59Qin.png) at the bottom you can clearly see that the test failed.

Comment: there is a green indicator above the tests themselves, even when the results panel shows failing.

Comment: @ChristianBaumann reorder images to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding here.
`pm.expect(true).to.eql(false);` throws an error.
If it is wrapped by a test, this error is being caught.
If no test wrapper, it's not being caught.

The red/ green dot next to "Tests" just indicates if the Javascript has been executed without problems.
So if you execute this as a test, the Javascript went trough without errors, thus the green dot. Because the error has been caught by the test function.
If you only execute the `.expect()` without a test, the error is not caught, thus the Javascript failed, thus the red dot.

Did you check the Test Results area at the bottom?
There you can clearly see, that a test which expects true to equal false is failing.

[image]

Comment: yeah that seems to be the thing, it's more of a UX confusion. thanks